# VBA Function That Works with Range and Array

Tags: arrays, vba, range, variant

I am trying to write a UDF that takes either a range or an array from the user and iterates over it. If I declare it as a range like so:

```
Function Test(param As Range) As Variant
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    total = 0
    For Each cell In param
        total = total + cell.Value2
    Next
    Test = total
End Function
```

it works fine when called like `=TEST(C22:C24)` but gives an error when called like `=TEST({1,2,3,4})`. On the other hand if I declare it as a variant like so:

```
Function Test(param As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, total As Integer
    total = 0
    On Error GoTo endfunc
    For i = 1 To 100
        total = total + param(i)
    Next
endfunc:
    Test = total
End Function
```

it works fine when called like `=TEST({1,2,3,4})` but when called like `=TEST(C22:C24)` it keeps on going way past the end of the range I give it (which is why I gave it the upper bound of 100). I can't use UBound on the variant to get the upper bound, it gives an error. Is there any way to get one function to work in both situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way...

```
Function Test(param As Variant) As Variant

    Dim total As Integer
    Dim item As Variant
    
    param = param
    
    If IsArray(param) Then
        total = 0
        For Each item In param
            total = total + item
        Next
    Else
        total = param
    End If
    
    Test = total
    
End Function
```

This part `param = param` does the following...

1. If `param` contains a Range object, it assigns the array of values from the range to the same variable, since the Value property is the default property of a Range object.
2. If `param` contains an array, it assigns that array to the same variable.
3. If `param` contains a single value, it assigns that value to the same variable.

Comment: Be carefull - if `param` is a Range and the Range contains formulas, the statement `param = param` will convert all formulas into values.

Comment: Followup: in my application I actually need to index into param, not just iterate over its elements. This is causing issues because an array formed from a range is two-dimensional but an array passed in natively is one dimensional, and `param(i)` and `param(i, 1)` are mutually incompatible. Is there any way I can use the same code to index into either structure? Do I just have to copy everything over into another array that I decide the dimensionality of?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Although `VarType(param)` gives `8204` in both cases `TypeName(param)` gives `Range` in the first case and `Variant()` in the second case. Using this the solution I found is

```
Function Test(param As Variant) As Variant
    Dim total As Integer
    total = 0
    If TypeName(param) = "Range" Then
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In param
            total = total + cell
        Next
    Else
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To UBound(param)
            total = total + param(i)
        Next
    End If
    Test = total
End Function
```